# Is there an absolute zero for internal energy?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, absolute-units

Of course we can arbitrarily define a reference point to call zero. However, I was under the impression that internal energy and enthalpy were relative and had no *absolute* zero, and only changes or relative values were physically meaningful. I was under the impression that this is different from entropy, which has an absolute zero point (based on Boltzmann's equation / the third law of thermodynamics).

I'll explain more details of what I think are the arguments for and against this conclusion. If anything I say is wrong, please correct me. I had a discussion with my thermodynamics professor about this, and he played devil's advocate.

My argument was:

1. Internal energy represents microscopic kinetic energies (translation, rotational, vibrational) as well as microscopic potential energies (intermolecular, sub-atomic).
2. Intermolecular forces are comparable to electrostatic forces (though some are more complex than a Coulmbic potential).
3. In a simple electrostatic Coulmbic potential, there is no absolute zero reference point. We may pick a relative zero reference point, such as when the particles are separated by an infinite distance, but that is a human convention. Only changes/relative values of potential energy are physically meaningful.
4. Therefore, internal energy (and thus enthalpy) have no absolute zero point and can only be expressed relative to a human-chosen reference point.

I'm not sure if I fully understand his position, but we ended up focusing on the simple system of the hydrogen atom and the representation of its energy (combined kinetic and potential) as Morse potential. He argued that the natural zero point of the energy was when the particles were infinitely separated (the horizontal asymptote). I argued that was useful but ultimately arbitrary, and nothing stops us from taking the energy at the bottom of the well to be zero, and I felt that demonstrated that the energy holding an atom together is relative and has no absolute zero. I'm not sure if this is correct.

There is also the issue of quantum zero-point energy; does it suggest an absolute zero point, or is there some assumption of a reference point made during the derivation of a model such as the quantum harmonic oscillator?

My professor then pointed out that my assumption that entropy has an absolute zero point might be incorrect. He said nothing stops us from defining entropy as $S=kln(W)$ plus any arbitrary constant, leading to a nonzero entropy even when only one microstate is present. I asked him if this meant that the third law of thermodynamics was not a law of nature, but a definition of the zero point of the function humans invented and call entropy. He agreed with this.

I have some concerns that entropy might be more fundamental than this, as the entropy (Shannon entropy) of something like a coin flip can be quantified in Information Theory, and I'm not sure if we can arbitrarily add constants to such a thing. Or maybe we can, since entropy is just a human-unvented mathematical object. But then the same should apply for temperature or pressure. Does this mean that temperature and pressure don't actually have an absolute zero, because we can also define them to be shifted by some constant? Does this imply there is really no such thing as absolute zero at all? Does it make a difference whether we are talking about a physical property or the mathematical function that represents it?

In summary, my question is whether internal energy, enthalpy, and entropy have absolute zero points, and what exactly that would mean.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

> He said nothing stops us from defining entropy as $S=k\ln(W)$ plus any arbitrary constant, leading to a nonzero entropy even when only one microstate is present.

But we don't.

Some simple examples:

- If we define the reference zero of **temperature** as the point at which the volume of an ideal gas is extrapolated to be zero, then we can all agree on that.
- If we define the reference zero of **pressure** as the absence of molecular collisions on a container wall, then we can all agree on that.
- If we define the reference zero of **entropy** as the ensemble configuration that can only be arranged a single way, then we can all agree on that.
- If we define the reference zero of **energy** as the configuration in which no more work can be extracted, then we can all agree on that—*except for the person moving at a different speed* (and special relativity tells us there's no preferred frame of reference). That person would be able to obtain work from the kinetic energy of our system.

Thus, for energy and all the associated potentials based on it (e.g., enthalpy, the Helmholtz free energy, and the Gibbs free energy and its molar version, the chemical potential), we can define a standard state from which we'll measure changes, but there's no "correct" absolute reference zero that can ever be determined.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've having trouble visualizing how an inertial observer in a different reference frame could obtain work from a system that we cannot (though I do understand that kinetic energy is relative). Could you perhaps illustrate this with a specific example? I'm also a bit uncertain of configurations in which "no more work can be extracted". Is that the case for an infinitely separated proton and electron (the horizontal asymptote of a Morse potential)?

Comment: They could slow the system to a halt in their frame and generate energy using [regenerative braking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_brake), for example. If such a tool is all we have at our disposal, no work can be extracted from an object at rest. This example can be extended to other work-producing mechanisms as you like.

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your point about relativity only affecting energy and not the other properties. But I feel intuitively that even besides that exception, energy is different. When you say we define "the reference zero of temperature" at some point, you really mean we define *temperature* in such a way that it is zero at that point, correct? Same for pressure and entropy. But for energy, while we can also define the energy such that it is zero at a certain point, why do we often put so much more emphasis on pointing out the state in which our definition of energy is zero ("the

Comment: reference state"), and rarely if ever point out the references states for temperature, pressure or entropy?

Comment: Because the reference zero for energy is arbitrary, unlike the other cases. (The existence of *offsets* such as 0°C, gauge pressure, and standard entropy doesn’t preclude true reference zeroes for these parameters.) Again using the ideal gas example, someone who ascribes a negative energy to an ideal gas in a certain frame can still do physics with no problem. But someone who obtains a negative pressure, temperature, or entropy has made a mistake.

Comment: Right, I think we're getting to the heart of my question. How can one *prove* the reference zero of energy is arbitrary in a way unlike those other properties? What argument is rigorous enough to convince a skeptical professor?

Comment: I can't augment my answer to address an objection I haven't heard yet.

Answer (score -2):

If there is no absolute value of internal energy (U) even at 0K, then the total energy calculated by DFT based techniques at 0K is exactly what?!

Comment: I'm sure if we read the fine print/inspected the code we would see there was a reference state deliberately chosen. But I have not verified this.